# Why is the "this" pointer null in a delegate?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code (details removed for clarity):

```
    private abstract class Base<TResult> {
        private readonly System.Func<TResult> func = null;

        protected Base(System.Func<TResult> func) {
            this.func = func;
        }

        public TResult Execute() {
            return this.func();
        }
    }

    private class Derived : Base<bool> {
        public Derived(bool myValue) : base(delegate() { return this.MyValue(); }) {
            this.myValue = myValue;
        }

        private bool myValue = false;
        private bool MyValue() {
            return this.myValue; // The "this" pointer is null here...
        }
    }

    Derived d = new Derived(true);
    bool result = d.Execute(); // This results in a null reference pointer (commented above)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks, Dave

Comment: why are you defining an abstract class as private?

Comment: @Mitch - it could be nested, in which case perfectly legal.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: sure, but a nested private abstract class doesn't sound very useful...

Comment: @Mitch - why not? He's showing a concrete implementation... add a factory: job done.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: probably just me, but I like to keep things simple. I mean one could shave with a scythe, but I probably wouldn't recommended it!

Comment: The code was for illustrative purposes only (and yes it was a nested class). My actual implementation is a public abstract class.

Answer (score 6):

Is that even *legal*? `this` is not defined at that point. IIRC, this is a compiler bug -  already fixed in 4.0.

Here it is in the 4.0 compiler:

> Error 1   Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context  C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs   22  40  ConsoleApplication1

To quote 7.5.7:

> A this-access is permitted only **in the block of an instance constructor**, an instance method, or an instance accessor. It has one of the following meanings:

(emph mine)

...

> Use of this in a primary-expression in a context other than the ones listed above is a compile-time error. In particular, it is not possible to refer to this in a static method, a static property accessor, or in a variable-initializer of a field declaration.

In the example given, it it simply invalid.

Comment: That makes sense - was using 3.5 without Resharper.

Comment: Marc, could you take a look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396782/why-is-the-this-pointer-null-in-a-delegate/3397108#3397108 beside IL is garbage I can't understand why `call instance` was used.

Answer (score 5):

Using `this` in a constructor is always dangerous (except in the special case where you are invoking a sibling constructor). Your `Derived` constructor captures `this` at the time of its invocation, which is null as the instance hasn't been constructed yet.

Comment: IIRC last time I saw this, the IL generated was garbage; it is simply a compiler bug –

Answer (score 1):

It is compiler bug and very weird. Let me explain details. I would be really happy if some experts clarify it.

Yes, it is incorrect to capture `this` in ctor, but the situation gets hot because `this` was used inside anonymous delegate. Normally, if anonymous delegate doesn't have closure (doesn't capture outer variables) it is implemented by compiler as static method of same class. It happened here. But let's take a look in IL code generated of that static method:

```
.method private hidebysig static bool <.ctor>b__0() cil managed
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor()
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] bool CS$1$0000)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldloc.0 
    L_0002: call instance bool ConsoleApplication15.Derived::MyValue()
    L_0007: stloc.0 
    L_0008: br.s L_000a
    L_000a: ldloc.0 
    L_000b: ret 
}
```

did you see that? take closer look at line `L_0002` and line `L_0001`. There are two extremely strange things:

1. We tried to call method `MyValue` against `bool`!
2. The method was called as `call` but it is not static, C# compiler usually call instance methods with `callvirt`! If the `callvirt` was used this call would fail, because `callvirt` checks for `this == null`.

Now let's break it. Let's introduce closure and change code to:

```
public Derived(bool myValue) : base(delegate() { return myValue ^ this.MyValue(); }) {
    this.myValue = myValue;
}
```

And now everything is fine! No NRE! Anonymous class was generated and it's fields capture the closure. In this case correct IL is generated:

```
.method public hidebysig instance bool <.ctor>b__0() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] bool CS$1$0000)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: ldfld bool ConsoleApplication15.Derived/<>c__DisplayClass1::myValue
    L_0007: ldarg.0 
    L_0008: ldfld class ConsoleApplication15.Derived ConsoleApplication15.Derived/<>c__DisplayClass1::<>4__this
    L_000d: call instance bool ConsoleApplication15.Derived::MyValue()
    L_0012: xor 
    L_0013: stloc.0 
    L_0014: br.s L_0016
    L_0016: ldloc.0 
    L_0017: ret 
}
```

Method is called against *closured* this. (but still with `call instance`, hmm)

Comment: It is a bug; therefore all bets/expectations of sanity are off - it isn't worth over-analysis...

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code I would say is a design problem...

Why don't you make the `Execute` function abstract and let the derived classes provide whatever implementation they want?

For example:

```
private abstract class Base<TResult> {
    public abstract TResult Execute();
}

private class Derived : Base<bool> {
    //...

    public override bool Execute(){
         return this.myValue;
    }

    //....
}

Derived d = new Derived(true);
bool result = d.Execute(); //This should work now
```

Comment: A valid alternative that I had thought about, but chose this route as a bit more generic. However, based on the feedback on the 4.0 compiler, it looks as if I will have to go that route.

Thanks to everyone for their input!

Cheers, Dave

Comment: @Dave: I'm not sure it will be more generic... What can you achieve with delegate but cannot be achieved with inheritance (in your case)?

Comment: My actual implementation was a bit more complex, and I was trying to keep my inheritance hierarchy a bit flatter through the use of Funcs and Actions. In hindsight however, I think my solution was more complex than it was worth. I'm off to rewrite it with abstract methods, or perhaps a generic interface. Thanks for the feedback!